# Use a different domain for SSL

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, ssl

long time lurker - first time poster.

A client of mine has a website developed in CakePHP, and a wordpress blog installed in the /blog/ directory.

Let's say the url of the main domain is `http://www.realdomain.com`, with the blog being `http://www.realdomain.com/blog/`.

They don't have their own SSL certificate so they use my companies. Let's say the secure URL is `https://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog/`

I have the following code in my wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.realdomain.com/blog/wp-content');
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

When I go to the /wp-login.php, it redirects me to the secure URL which is perfect.

However, when I log in to the secure site, WordPress tries to loads JavaScripts and styles from

```
`http**s**://realdomain.com`
```

Which causes problems because the main site doesn't have a SSL certificate and as a result doesn't load anything from `https://realdomain.com`

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Is the solution a .htaccess rule?
A rule which routed all "`https://realdomain.com`" to `"https://realdomain.maindomain.com`"?

I'll pay anyone $20 who can help me fix it. I've Google'd until my hearts content and I don't know what else I can do.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10):

Just to keep things nice & clear, I've posted this as a new answer. Let's reset the playing field & follow the below instructions as if it were a shiny new install (ignore all code & suggestions in previous answers).

In your `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.realdomain.com/blog' );
define( 'SSL_DOMAIN_ALIAS', 'realdomain.maindomain.net' );

define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

And in `wp-content/mu-plugins/ssl-domain-alias.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: SSL Domain Alias
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38902
 * Description: Use a different domain for serving your website over SSL, set with <code>SSL_DOMAIN_ALIAS</code> in your <code>wp-config.php</code>.
 * Author: TheDeadMedic
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic
 *
 * @package SSL_Domain_Alias
 */

/**
 * Swap out the current site domain with {@see SSL_DOMAIN_ALIAS} if the
 * protocol is HTTPS.
 *
 * This function is not bulletproof, and expects both {@see WP_SITEURL} and
 * {@see SSL_DOMAIN_ALIAS} to be defined.
 *
 * @todo The replacement is a simple string replacement (for speed). If the
 * domain name is matching other parts of the URL other than the host, we'll
 * need to switch to a more rigid regex.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function _use_ssl_domain_alias_for_https( $url )
{
    static $domain;
    if ( ! isset( $domain ) )
        $domain = defined( 'WP_SITEURL' ) && defined( 'SSL_DOMAIN_ALIAS' ) ? parse_url( WP_SITEURL, PHP_URL_HOST ) : false;

    if ( $domain && strpos( $url, 'https' ) === 0 )
        $url = str_replace( $domain, SSL_DOMAIN_ALIAS, $url );

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'plugins_url', '_use_ssl_domain_alias_for_https', 1 );
add_filter( 'content_url', '_use_ssl_domain_alias_for_https', 1 );
add_filter( 'site_url', '_use_ssl_domain_alias_for_https', 1 );

?>
```

I've suggested using a Must-Use plugin (**mu**-plugins), since these are autoloaded without having to be activated first.

If you'd rather it be a standard plugin, you'll need to add the `FORCE_SSL_*` constants *after* activation.

Comment: Nice answer. I can not get this working with wordpress 3.3.2 and this two domains: http://myblog.tld && https://ssl.company.tld/myblog.tld. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I can confirm that this solution still works on Wordpress 3.5.1. Thank you.

Comment: I can confirm too that this solution still works on Wordpress 4.2.3

Answer (score 3):

I banged my head against the wall trying to move the admin functions on wordpress to a separate server.  I thought I'd just add to it that having two host names does break the "preview" function in the editor, and so you need to modify your .htaccess to make that work again.

```
#special fixes on previews when wordpress sends user to the public blog & we want the hidden one.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^public.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*(/?preview=true.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*&preview=true.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://secure.site.com/$1$2  [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will force HTTPS for all assets if the current protocol is SSL. I'm assuming `realdomain.maindomain.net` is an alias for `realdomain.com`?

If so, set your content URL to `http://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog/wp-content`.

All assets will be served from this URL, and automatically rewritten to HTTPS when required.

If (for whatever reason) you only ever want to serve content from the aliased domain inside the admin (i.e. via HTTPS), you can change the content URL conditionally:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.realdomain.com/blog/wp-content' );

function use_alias_for_ssl( $url )
{
    if ( is_ssl() )
        $url = str_replace( 'www.realdomain.com', 'realdomain.maindomain.net', $url );
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'content_url', 'use_alias_for_ssl' );
add_filter( 'plugins_url', 'use_alias_for_ssl' );
```

**UPDATE:** Try this, without any of the previous filters or additional defines;

```
/* wp-config.php */
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog' );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );

/* wp-content/mu-plugins/any-filename.php */
add_filter( 'blog_option_siteurl', '_config_wp_siteurl' );
```

Comment: Thanks!
Yes, realdomain.maindomain.net is an alias for realdomain.com

I've added what you suggested to my wp-config.php file and the it still tries to get stuff from https://www.realdomain.com/

When you're on the wp-login.php, the form POSTs to `https://realdomain.maindomain.net` but once you've logged in, it gets some stuff from the right domain and then stuff from the wrong domain. 
http://i.imgur.com/pcIrO.png
Here's an image of what's happening (ignore those <br>'s, just added them for spacing for you).
The problem is /wp-admin/load-scripts.php and /wp-includes/
Other than that it works!

Comment: Are you still defining `WP_SITEURL`?

Comment: define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.realdomain.com/blog/wp-content');

Yes mate, I used the above + the function you posted, tried it in the functions.php and wp-config and nothing

Comment: Add `add_filter( 'includes_url', 'use_alias_for_ssl' );` to the mix

Comment: Hi Pal,
Added includes_url to the functions.php in my theme folder, it didn't have any effect.
Just to confirm, in my wp-config.php, WP_SITEURL = secure version
WP_CONTENTURL = normal version

That's all the new stuff in the wp-config.

In the functions.php
The function in your first post followed by 3 add_filters..

Is that correct? 

The same thing is happening in the screenshot in my 2nd post. It's giving me a serious headache. I didn't think it would be this hard, and I think it's just me who is having the problem... I haven't read anything with a similar problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I updated the wp-config.php and WordPress MU isn't installed, so I created the mu-plugins folder in the /wp-content/ folder. A few things happened:
When viewing the public side, it loaded certain files from `https://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog` and some from `http://realdomain.com`. Like this:

`<script src="http://www.realdomain.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/commentluv/js/commentluv.js?ver=3.2.1" type="text/javascript">`

`<link href="https://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog/xmlrpc.php?rsd" title="RSD" type="application/rsd+xml" rel="EditURI">`

`<link href="https://realdomain.maindomain.net/blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" rel="wlwmanifest">`

However, blog post URLs and thumbnails were linking correctly. It was just 4 files which were retrieved from the https:// site

On the wp-login page, the form URL was correct, https:// and it loaded the secure site..
However, I didn't change anything. It still pulls in 7 `<script>` & `<link>` files from `https://realdomain.com`.

The URLs on all the `<forms>` all POST to the correct https:// site..

Thanks for all your help so far, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

To enable admin access for http://blog.example.com through https://ssl.example.com/wp-admins/blog/wp-login.php with pure Apache config so you have no dependence on Wordpress plugins and updates you may want to...

...use mod_proxy on an HTTPS apache virtual host to forward traffic, ensure ProxyPreserveHost is Off so that host names in the proxy statements are sent through to the wordpress server. Then mod_substitute is used (make sure to turn it on) to fix the broken links coming back from wordpress.

```
<Location /wp-admins/blog/>

  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/json
  Substitute "s|http://blog.example.com|https://ssl.example.com/wp-admins/blog|i"
  Substitute "s|blog.example.com\\\/|blog.example.com\\/wp-admins\\/blog\\/|i"
  Substitute "s|'/wp-admin|'/wp-admins/blog/wp-admin|i"
  Substitute "s|\"/wp-admin|\"/wp-admins/blog/wp-admin|i"
  Substitute "s|'/wp-includes|'/wp-admins/blog/wp-includes|i"
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /wp-admins/blog/

</Location>

ProxyPass /wp-admins/blog/ http://blog.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /wp-admins/blog/ http://blog.example.com/
```

For the reverse proxy to work, you need to specify the internal IP of the server hosting blog.example.com. This solution ensures this will work even if the upstream server (10.0.0.4) has several name-based virtual hosts.

```
10.0.0.4 blog.example.com
```

For more details, see:

http://tec.libertar.se/how-to-host-wordpress-admin-on-a-seperate-domain-and-subfolder/